# API Routes - API resolved without sending a response for xxxx, this may result in stalled requests

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am currently trying to implement a simple api call on my frontend and decided to go with API routes. I am getting the following error when trying to complete the api call, stalling my redirect on the frontend:

> API resolved without sending a response for /api/uploadLog, this may
> result in stalled requests.

I have read the solution to other developers to no avail, I might be doing something wrong not understanding what is going on under the hood.

This code doesn't work:

```
    export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    fs.readdir('./src/data/logs', (err, files) => {
        if (!err) {
            const logNumber = files.length;
            fs.writeFileSync(`./src/data/logs/log${logNumber}.txt`, req.body);
            res.status(200).json({ message: `log${logNumber}` });
        } else {
            res.status(500).json({ message: err });
        }
    });
};
```

However this one does resolve:

```
export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    fs.readdir('./src/data/logs', (err, files) => {
        if (!err) {
            const logNumber = files.length;
            fs.writeFileSync(`./src/data/logs/log${logNumber}.txt`, req.body);
        } else {
            res.status(500).json({ message: err });
        }
    });
    res.status(200).json({ message: `Hello World!` });
};
```

I can't use the last approach because I need to first resolve the readdir.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try adding a console log inside `readdir`'s callback. Is it firing?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar I was mistaken on my last reply. It is firing yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by changing the readdir call to readdirSync and making the call async. It isn't stalling anymore and correctly returning the right response. Below is what I came up with:

```
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    try {
        const logs = fs.readdirSync('./src/data/logs').length;
        fs.writeFileSync(`./src/data/logs/log${logNumber}.txt`, req.body);
        res.status(200).json({ message: `log${logNumber}` });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: err });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`readdir` is async. So your first one is calling readdir, but not waiting for the Promise to resolve (basically fire and forget).

Try using `readdirSync`

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-readdir-method/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-readdirsync-method/

Your second one resolves because you call `res.status(200).json({...` outside of your callback.

Try something like:

```
import fs from 'fs';

export default function handler(req, res) {
  try{
    const files = fs.readdirSync('./src/data/logs');

    const logNumber = files.length;
    fs.writeFileSync(`./src/data/logs/log${logNumber}.txt`, req.body || '');
    return res.status(200).json({ message: `log${logNumber}` });
  } catch(e){
    return res.status(500).json({ message: e.message });
  }
}
```

Comment: If I use your code exactly, the response is a 500 with the message "shouldn't get here" and I get an error saying "uncaughtException: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client", If I remove the last line of code and just leave the readdir call, I get the same behavior I was getting earlier, with the status code 200 and the log number correctly put on the response, but still the same problem occurs with stalling.

Comment: Ye sorry, I messed up there, you can't use it that way. It would be better to use readDirSync. Which I see you've done. Updated my answer to account